# How I can change font in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, fonts, texworks

I'd like to change the font off all slides (not dimension of the words, but the type of font). Can anyone help me please? I'm working on TeXWorks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add details what property of the font you'd like to change. Do you want to change the series, e.g. to serif or the complete font family?